# Is it poosible to covert .html file to .jsp

Tags: html, jsp

User will upload .htm file and that uploaded file i have to convert to .jsp .
User will give me plain html file only with design and required fields. When he will upload I have to parse ans copy all html content also i have to add additional scripts and jstl code in jsp file. Is there any easy way to do this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: on file upload you can change .html to .jsp, is that only you needed? Then it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have to copy all contents of uploaded html file into jsp file and also i have to add my new  new scripts for validation in jsp file created.

Answer (score 0):

Handle it through file extension through servlet.

```
private String extractFileName(Part part) {
    String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
    for (String s : items) {
        if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            String cccfileName = s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length() - 1);

            return cccfileName.substring(cccfileName.lastIndexOf("."), cccfileName.length());
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Use it like String fileNameExt = extractFileName(part); and change the file extension to .jsp, it should work.

Comment: I dont want to only change the extension. I have parse my htm file copy it into jsp file and also have to add new scripts in jsp. All this i have to do programatically